# Non-interactive way to connect via SSH (possible options)

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, sshpass

I am trying to create a generic bash script to connect to the remote server via SSH using a non-interactive approach (using `sshpass`). All I need to know is the possible way to connect via SSH.

So far, I know you can use a password and key file (with passphrase, if set) to connect:

1. Login via password

   ```
   sshpass -p {ssh-pass} ssh {ssh-user}@{ssh-host} -p {ssh-port}
   ```
2. Login via key (without passphrase)

   ```
   ssh -i {ssh-key} {ssh-user}@{ssh-host} -p {ssh-port}
   ```
3. Login via key (with a passphrase)

   ```
   sshpass -Ppassphrase -p {passphrase} ssh -i {ssh-key} {ssh-user}@{ssh-host} -p {ssh-port}
   ```
4. ???

Comment: What's the question? I've failed to parse this. *"If a command is specified, it will be executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."*

Comment: All I need to know is the possible way to connect via SSH.

Comment: In what way 1, 2 and 3 are not enough for you? What do you need to fix? What do you expect from 4?

Comment: What about pub keys-based authentication? id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you've learned one of the important and occasionally painful lessons of security:

**Automation and security are not aligned**.

In order to automate things to run in a script, you need to make sure the script can access all credentials without further interaction from you. But this means that said credentials need to be available *somehow*, which means passing them on the command line (**BAD** idea, because anyone who can read `ps` can divine them) or in a file that can only be read by the script's user.

My go-to solution for automated scripts that are run via scheduler and require non-interactive SSH is to create a passwordless key that's going to be exclusively used for that purpose and that purpose only; this optionally allows me to control what it can and cannot do via the `authorized_keys` file on the receiving end. This key is then stored in a file that's readable only to the user the script runs at.

On the other hand, if this is a script you intend to run manually and just don't want to be bothered with being prompted for a password in the middle of it, what you want is an **SSH key agent**.

If you're using a GNOME desktop environment I know for a fact that gnome-keyring can and does act as an SSH key agent, and you can simply read the key into it with `ssh-add` -- at which point any ssh process started from anywhere within the gnome desktop environment will be able to contact the agent and use its stored credentials until such time as you end the session or clear the key from the keyring.

```
shadur@luminosity:~$ ssh-add .ssh/id_ed25519
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_ed25519: 
Identity added: .ssh/id_ed25519 (Shadur - 2020)
shadur@luminosity:~$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:e3gvrdo**************FxJCtPo7DYN Shadur - 2020 (ED25519)
shadur@luminosity:~$
```

(Actual fingerprint has been fudged)

Furthermore, if you're looking to automate remote scripts, I cannot recommend looking into [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/) enough.